# Haxe: check if a dynamic type is an Object

Tags: types, haxe

I need to check if `var a : Dynamic = {}` is an object. So I'm expecting:

```
var a : Dynamic;
a = 17.2; check( a ); // false
a = "test"; check( a ); // false
a = [1,2,3]; check( a ); // false
a = 99; check( a ); // false
a = {b:1, c:2}; check( a ); // true
```

Here is what I have (slightly different from above, as it checks for multiple types and returns an enum). It all works, except the object line:

```
function check( v : Dynamic ) : TokenType {
    if ( Std.is(v, std.Array) ) return TTArray;
    else if ( Std.is(v, std.String) ) return TTString;
    else if ( Std.is(v, Object) ) return TTObject; // What do I need here?
    else if ( Math.isNaN( v ) ) return TTUnknown;
    else if ( Std.is(v, StdTypes.Float) ) return TTNumber;
    else if ( Std.is(v, StdTypes.Int) ) return TTNumber;
    return TTUnknown;
}
```

Note - this is tiny snippet of a much larger class. The type has to be `Dynamic` (I can't use `Any` for example).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options here:

- [`Type.typeof(v) == TObject`](https://api.haxe.org/Type.html#typeof)
- [`Reflect.isObject(v)`](https://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#isObject)

The former may be a bit more reliable for your use case, since classes are a separate [`ValueType`](https://api.haxe.org/ValueType.html). For instance, on the JS target `Type.typeof("string")` will result in `TClass(String)`, while you simply get `true` with `Reflect.isObject()`.